# How to add specified web application to DNS by pinging it

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, web-application, dns

I have created a sharepoint web application using powershell. I want to add my web application to default DNS. How i add it using powershell?

Comment: What you mean by default DNS?

Comment: DNS on my system

Comment: Do you mean "hosts" file ? A thought : if you only create web application site collection along, it won't respond (in a web way).

Comment: Like we manually add entry to host file somthing like this: (127.0.0.1  MySite). Similarly i want to add this entry using powershell. How i can do this?